# group by query with not in sub query linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Hello i have `sql` query

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1 ,column2 ,column3 FROM tableA
WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM tableA WHERE DATE(column2) <= '2016-05-01') AND column4 != 'Bonus'GROUP BY column1
```

I tried to convert it to `linq` query , Here is the sample code what i tried

```
 var value = from name in DB.tableA
 where name .column4 != "Bonus" && !(from name2 in DB.tableA
 where name2.column2.Day >= 1 && name2.column2.Month == today.Month && name2.column2.Year == today.Year
select new { name2.column1, name2.column2, name2.column3 })
group customer by name.column1 into Agroup
select Agroup;
```

Can you please mention the error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Query is wrong, when you `GROUPBY` `column1`, you can only select `column1` or use `Aggregate` functions on the other columns **(SUM ,AVG, MAX ... )**

You can do this:

```
DateTime queryDate = new DateTime(2016, 05, 01);

var value = from name in DB.tableA
            where name.column4 != "Bonus" &&
            DB.tableA.Any(x=> x.column2.Date <= queryDate && x.column1 == name.column1)
            group name by name.column1 into grp
            select new
            {
                Column1 = grp.Key,
                // you can use grp.key, grp.SUM(), grp.MAX(), grp.MIN(), grp.Count() ...
                // to execute aggregate over each group

            };
```

Also, using `Distinct` with `GroupBy` is pointless. `GroupBy` already returns **only 1 row for each Group**.